# Vertex shader with extrusion, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: unity, shaders

So for a simple surface shader, you can use vertex modifier:

```
    void vert (inout appdata_full v) {
        v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * _Amount;
    }
```

I was thinking the same would work as vertex shader:

```
    // vertex shader
    VectexOutput vert (VectexInput i) {
        // init output
        VectexOutput o;
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(VectexOutput, o);

        // vertex extrusion
        i.vertex.xyz += i.normal * _Multiplier;

        // world space normal
        half3 normal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(i.normal);

        // standard diffuse lighting
        half nl = max(0, dot(normal, _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz));

        // input to output
        o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(i.vertex);
        o.color = i.color;
        o.diff = nl * _LightColor0;
        o.diff.rgb += ShadeSH9(half4(normal, 1));
        o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv, _MainTex);

        return o;
    }
```

But it doesn't, and since surface shader is compiled to vertex/fragment shader, I am wondering what am I missing?

Comment: There is also [an example](https://github.com/nanclin/Fun-with-Unity/blob/master/vertex%20animation.shader) so very similar to mine ([and works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4MEttgakTc)), I just could not figure out why mine doesn't work.

Comment: For future reference, when describing something that "doesn't work" it's very helpful to describe *the precise way* in which it does not work. Eg. Does it have no effect? Does it have a particular effect different from what you intended? (How does it differ?) Does it generate an error message or crash your program? (What error message/debug info?) etc. I gather from context here "doesn't work" means no effect at all, but it's good to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

I declared `_Multiplier` incorrectly in the `SubShader` block.

It should have been `uniform float _Multiplier`, but I wrote `uniform float4 _Multiplier;`

Interesting part is: no error will be produced, because `float4 _Multiplier` defaults to `(0,0,0,0)`, so `i.vertex.xyz += i.normal * _Multiplier;` result in zero float3, hence no change in vertex position.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer "Accepted" the next tome you're back. ;) Otherwise the Community user keeps bumping the question for new attention periodically.